# bool operator== within typedef struct

Tags: c++, struct

How can I add the bool operator== to the struct `bd_addr_t`? I'm using this file within a C++ project.

```
#ifndef APITYPES_H_
#define APITYPES_H_

#ifdef __GNUC__

#define PACKSTRUCT( decl ) decl __attribute__((__packed__))
#define ALIGNED __attribute__((aligned(0x4)))

#else //msvc

#define PACKSTRUCT( decl ) __pragma( pack(push, 1) ) decl __pragma( pack(pop) )
#define ALIGNED

#endif


typedef unsigned char  uint8;
typedef unsigned short uint16;
typedef signed short   int16;
typedef unsigned long  uint32;
typedef signed char    int8;

typedef struct bd_addr_t
{
    uint8 addr[6];

}bd_addr;

typedef bd_addr hwaddr;
typedef struct
{
    uint8 len;
    uint8 data[];
}uint8array;

typedef struct
{
    uint8 len;
    int8 data[];
}string;

#endif
```

I tried to add

```
bool operator==(const bd_addr_t& a) const
    {
        return (addr[0] == a.addr[0] && addr[1] == a.addr[1] && addr[2] == a.addr[2] && addr[3] == a.addr[3] && addr[4] == a.addr[4] && addr[5] == a.addr[5]);
    }
```

but this throws two errors during compilation:

```
unknown type name 'bool' bool operator==(const bd_addr_t& a) const

 expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '__attribute__' before '==' token bool operator==(const bd_addr_t& a) const
```

Comment: Are you really using a C++ compiler on this file? Looks like it's unaware of typical C++ features.

Comment: Why do you use `typedef struct` in C++?

Comment: Are you sure this is being compiled in C++?  IIRC `uint8 data[];` is a flexible array member and is not standard in C++.

Comment: Where did you add this definition? This looks like C code, are you sure the compiler is compiling as c++?

Comment: This is a file from the [bglib](https://github.com/jrowberg/bglib/blob/master/MSVCSharp/Examples/BLEScanner/bglib/apitypes.h) I use within a Qt project.

Comment: The files there have a .c file extension so I suspect they are supposed to be compiled with a C compiler.

Comment: Yes, but I want to use the lib within a Qt project and until now everything works fine. Isn't there a way to use the operator?

Comment: @schnarchnase The library is presumably written in C, and expects the structure to have normal C layout. If you add C++ features to it, that will change the layout, so the library won't be able to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add such function into this header which is used by C compiler as well. One of the way could be to create a wrapper header that you use only in you C++ code and add standalone function (it cannot be a method as that would require it's declaration within struct and make that code incompatible with C):

```
#include <original_header.h>
#ifndef __cplusplus
#error This header is only to be included in C++ code
#endif 

bool operator==(const bd_addr_t& a, const bd_addr_t& b);
```

and then implement it in one of .cpp files or you can implement it in this header and make that function `inline`